# R caret package createDataPartition() function not giving the correct number of partition

Tags: r

I have below code. My understanding is that it will give 50*0.8 = 40 entries back but it gives 42. 
Appreciate it if anyone can help to explain this.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
x <- seq(1:50)
training_index <- createDataPartition(x, times = 1, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
dim(training_index)
```

Comment: This gives me 25 `dim(createDataPartition(x, p=0.8,list=F, groups=2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn off the groups default value to 2 to get exact proportions.

use this `createDataPartition(x, p=0.8,list=F, groups=2)`

Comment: So helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please accept my answer if this solved your problem

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie here. Just accepted the answer. Really appreciate it.